# Proving generated algebra is finite unions of disjoint subjsets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let F be a semi-ring of subsets of S such that S ∈ F. I need to show the algebra generated by F consists of finite unions of disjoint subsets of F.

At first I tried to prove using the definition if the semi-ring but I soon ran into a wall. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first let $\mathcal{R}$ be the class of all sets formed by disjoint unions of sets in your semi-ring $F$, now you can show the following

1. $\mathcal{R}$ is closed under finite interesections and *disjoint* unions
2. If $A,B \in \mathcal{R}$ with $A \subset B$ then $B-A \in \mathcal{R}$

So property 2. is one of the things we need to show, the other is that the ring is closed under any finite union, so use these properties to rewrite an arbitrary union of two sets in $\mathcal{R}$ as a union of disjoint sets.